# Svelte can't find .ScrollTop of a variable

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

Hello I have an element which is being referenced to the script like this

```html
<div bind:this={AboutMeAnimation} />
```

and then In my script I console log ScrollTop value

```js
    let AboutMeAnimation;
    console.log(AboutMeAnimation.ScrollTop);
```

and for some resson I'm getting an error can some one tell me why?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues, the first is that is [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) with a lowercase “s”, the other is that the element does not bind immediately so if you are putting this statement at the top level of the component it will be undefined for some period of time. You can use onMount or similar to get this value:

```
onMount(() => {
  console.log(AboutMeAnimation.scrollTop);
});
```

Otherwise a reactive statement could work also:

```
$: {
  console.log(AboutMeAnimation && AboutMeAnimation.scrollTop);
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: it looks to work but for some reason `console.log` gives me 0 and by the way what will happen if the user will change the size of the window will the value adapt?

Comment: @LAYTOR Element.scrollTop returns 0 when the content of the element being evaluated does not generate a vertical scrollbar. As for your question about values being updated, they will if you use Alexander's second solution, provided the value of scrollTop actually changes because of the resize.